# Weird singleTask behaviour

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode

I understand that launchMode:"singleTask" means that if an activity has previously been created and is requested in future to show up , Android will simply show the old one instead of creating a new instance. The problem i am facing can be illustrated with an example :-

Lets Say we have two activities 
**A**  actvity 
**B** (Activity with launchMode="singleTask") enabled (This is all that is in its Manifest Declaration)

Now , if A creates an Intent which corresponds to B (A->B) , then A gets Finished and is removed from the activity stack . How can i prevent this from happening . What i want is that when A calls B (Creates an Intent) previous instance of B is returned and A remains as it is and is not destroyed . Thank you for helping . Any help is appreciated

EDIT

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.Activities.A"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.Activities.B"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I don't believe, from what I understand, that what you want is possible. Perhaps you need to rethink what it is that needs to be kept and consider other ways of keeping it. However, what if B were to start, know that A hasn't start A which then returns to B?

Comment: Could you please suggest me a  solution , i have tried almost everything .  Thanks!

Comment: Above comment amended to make it clearer. Sorry ran out of time. Perhaps you need to rethink what it is that needs to be kept and consider other ways of keeping it. However, what if B were to start, know that A hasn't been started, immediately start A (i.e B just basically flags A as now having been started), which then returns to B?

Comment: The obvious solution is to not use `singleTask` or `singleInstance` and work with `standard`. Why couldn't that be possible?

Comment: Because standard would always create a new instance of any activity to which an intent is made. That is something i dont want. I want to get the previous instance

Comment: Could you just suggest me a combination of flags . PS . I tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT ..and that froze my device

Comment: Have you checked whether `finishOnTaskLaunch` (false) or (unlikely and) `allowTaskReparenting` could do accomplish you want? That's all I can think of. I assume that you've looked at

Comment: In the manifest activity

Comment: Yep. Have a look at [<activity>](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: No Luch :( , I ve posted the activity declaration from my manifest could have a look maybe something can be done there

Comment: What i want is basically that if we have two activities and one calls another  then the previous instance should be opened and not a new activity . Could you tell me how can i achieve that

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have 2 activities that switch back and forth in the same task, then you should remove all special launch modes and just launch one activity from the other like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityX.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you start `B` from `A` using this method and also start `A` from `B` using this method, then you will have one instance of each `Activity` in your task and they will just change positions in the stack. This won't create any new instances.

Also remove the `<intent-filter>` declarations, you don't need them. You only need one for the root `Activity` which should contain "ACTION=MAIN" and "CATEGORY=LAUNCHER".